# Rails Facebook-like search field with suggestions that link to the the result?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, search, user-interface, autocomplete

How can I duplicate the search function that Facebook has? Specifically, I want a list of suggestions to drop down as I type, and if I click on a suggestion, it should link to it.

Here's the search function I have currently:

**views/layouts/application.rb**

```
<%= form_tag articles_path, :method => :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
  <button class="btn" type="submit"><i class="article-search">GO</i></button>
<% end %>
```

---

**articles_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @article = Article.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
end
```

---

**models/article.rb**

```
def self.search(query)
  where("title like ?" "%#{query}%")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

i have accomplished similar functionality with token input plugin. On the [demos](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/demo.html) page check one with heading "Token and Results Formatting", below is the link of demos page. TokenInput plugin was good, and with little tweaks in CSS i got desired results.

```
http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/demo.html
```

Comment: That seems to just autocomplete the search term. Could you get it to actually link straight to the result?